# spread operator issues with property accessors (getters)

Tags: javascript, babeljs

I'm having a hard time understanding why there are some issues with the following code https://jsfiddle.net/q4w6e3n3/3/

**Note:** All examples are tested in chrome version 52.0.2743.116 just in case this helps

```
const model = {
  someVal: 'some val',
};


const obs = {
  ...model,
  get accessor() {
    return this.someVal;
  },
}

// Expected: '>>> some val'
// Actual: '>>> undefined'
console.log('>>>', obs.accessor);
```

But the following similar snippet works https://jsfiddle.net/q4w6e3n3/5/

```
const model = {
  someVal: 'some val',
};


const obs = {
  get accessor() {
    return this.someVal;
  },
  ...model,
}

// Expected: '>>> some val'
// Actual: '>>> some val'
console.log('>>>', obs.accessor);
```

using the babel REPL I was able to see that `Object.assign` is used if available in the transpiled code
When I used it directly instead of the object spread I get the same issue, and also works if put the `model`
variable to the end instead of at the beginning.

Is this a bug? or is it intended behavior?

Also why does the following snippet work as well?:

```
const model = {
  someVal: 'some val',
};


const obs = {
  someVal: model.someVal,
  get accessor() {
    return this.someVal;
  },
}

// Expected: '>>> some val'
// Actual: '>>> some val'
console.log('>>>', obs.accessor);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/q4w6e3n3/6/

I would expect it to have the same issues but works as a charm are getters `this` keyword somehow bound to the object they were added to?

Comment: This appears to be a bug in the transpilation, it should not use `Object.assign` for "own" properties. You should report it to the plugin.

Comment: The `this` object follows the standard rules. When you call the getter like `obs.accessor`, then `this` will (should) be `obs` (except if it was explicitly bound, which is not the case here). This turns out not to be the case where you get `undefined` as output, which is explained by the  `Object.assign` you found.  Note the difference when you add `console.log(abs === this);` in the getter. This is not good.

Comment: not sure `Object.assign` causes the issue here. the context seems to be bound to the original object when using the `get` syntax a normal method works just fine, as shown here https://jsfiddle.net/q4w6e3n3/8/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Object.assign won't copy accessors. So when your splat is before your getter babel and its various voodoos uses Object.assign and the accessor isn't copied onto the first object from the second, well kind of, voodoo again. When your splat is after the getter, then it assigns the splatted properties onto the object with the getter, and the getter is preserved.

See here: [MDN - Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

Relevant code excerpt:

```
**Copying Accessors**
var obj = {
  foo: 1,
  get bar() {
    return 2;
  }
};

var copy = Object.assign({}, obj); 
console.log(copy); 
// { foo: 1, bar: 2 }, the value of copy.bar is obj.bar's getter's return value.

// This is an assign function that copies full descriptors
function completeAssign(target, ...sources) {
  sources.forEach(source => {
    let descriptors = Object.keys(source).reduce((descriptors, key) => {
      descriptors[key] = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(source, key);
      return descriptors;
    }, {});
    // by default, Object.assign copies enumerable Symbols too
    Object.getOwnPropertySymbols(source).forEach(sym => {
      let descriptor = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(source, sym);
      if (descriptor.enumerable) {
        descriptors[sym] = descriptor;
      }
    });
    Object.defineProperties(target, descriptors);
  });
  return target;
}

var copy = completeAssign({}, obj);
console.log(copy);
// { foo:1, get bar() { return 2 } }
```