# Cannot extend typescript File

Tags: javascript, typescript, type-conversion, typescript-typings

I am creating a drag and drop interface. On drop, I get the native `File`. I need to extend this interface and include a few other information.

My first approach was using

```
interface AcceptedFile extends File {
   acl: Acl,
   disabled: boolean;
}

const toAcceptedFiles = (files: File[]): AcceptedFile[] => {
   return files.map(file => {
      return {
         ...file,
         acl: Acl.Public,
         disabled: false
      }
   });
}
```

However, the result of the function `toAcceptedFiles`, only contains the `preview` key from the `File`; all the blob, name, etc is gone. If I `console.log` the `file` inside the `toAcceptedFiles`, I can see all the keys.

The interesting thing is, the following interface works fine:

```
interface AcceptedFile {
   file: File,
   acl: Acl,
   disabled: boolean;
}
```

Why is extending the `File` breaking it?

Comment: I’m pretty sure that you likely cannot just copy over the native `File` object while also expecting it to continue working. It’s likely that it has some internal properties that you simply don’t have access to (e.g. an memory pointer where the data is stored or something browser-specific). So you should probably just wrap it in a custom object instead of copying it to a custom type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why the first approach won't work 
[spread operator issues with property accessors (getters)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39515321/spread-operator-issues-with-property-accessors-getters)

Your second approach is more reasonable since the native api will give back to you a `File[]` which you want to map to your type `AcceptedFile`.

```
const toAcceptedFiles = (files: File[]): AcceptedFile[] => {
   return files.map(file => {
      return {
         file: file,
         acl: Acl.Public,
         disabled: false
      }
   });
}
```

When `toAcceptedFiles` is called from the native API it will be populated with `File[]` and not `AcceptedFile[]`.

```
interface AcceptedFile {
   file: File;
   acl: Acl,
   disabled: boolean;
}
```

Comment: But that's not my problem. my `onDrop` function takes in an `File[]`. I then pass that into `toAcceptedFiles` but when it is converted, it has lost all the blob information about the file. My first approach does not even work

Comment: I am pretty sure the spread operator `...file` is breaking something

Comment: Did you make `acl` and `disabled` optional?

Comment: Yes, again the problem is if I console log what I get from `toAcceptedFiles`, it only contains the properties `acl`, `disabled`, and `preview`. But console.logging the `file` inside the map function, also shows the size, type, name, etc

Comment: `{...file}` performs shallow copy of the actual `File` so most of the actual data will get lost.

Comment: So basically only the the second approach will work. Adding a `file` member to the mapped object.

Comment: Ok, makes sense about the shallow copy. What if i don't want to do that? What if the first approach is the approach I want? How do I not get a shallow copy?

Comment: There are deep merge modules you can use off the self. But it's not a good idea since it will come at unnecessary time and memory cost.

Comment: If you inspect the `File` object in the browser console you'll notice that all its properties are `getters` and not simple properties. That is why spread doesn't work.

Comment: The Object.assign() method only copies enumerable and own properties from a source object to a target object. It uses [[Get]] on the source and [[Set]] on the target, so it will invoke getters and setters. Therefore it assigns properties versus just copying or defining new properties. This may make it unsuitable for merging new properties into a prototype if the merge sources contain getters. For copying property definitions, including their enumerability, into prototypes